# email id search is not working in mongodb full text search

Tags: node.js, mongodb, indexing

i have my collection something like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58492f1a23e7a2bc20a252ce"),
    "type" : "valuation",
    "quote" : {
        "schedule" : "no",
        "valuation" : "XXX",
        "designation" : "III",
        "companyname" : "XYZ",
        "city" : "Delhi",
        "country" : "India",
        "phone" : "991147****",
        "email" : "atul.agrawal@abc.com",
        "mobile" : "991147****",
        "lname" : "Agrawal",
        "fname" : "Atul",
        "product" : {
            "contactNumberAsAbove" : true,
            "contactPersonAsAbove" : true,
            "description" : "Test obj",
            "mfgYear" : 2009,
            "city" : "Delhi",
            "model" : "2518",
            "brand" : "Ashtt9t",
            "category" : "Tipjbih"
        }
    },
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-12-08T09:59:54.686Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58492f8e23e7a2bc20a252d1"),
    "type" : "shipping",
    "quote" : {
        "comment" : "Hello World",
        "packaging" : "no",
        "allowed" : "no",
        "designation" : "II",
        "companyname" : "XYZ",
        "city" : "Delhi",
        "country" : "India",
        "phone" : "99114733**",
        "email" : "atul.agrawal@xyz.com",
        "mobile" : "99114733**",
        "lname" : "Agrawal",
        "fname" : "Atul"
    },
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-12-08T10:01:50.001Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

now when i made this query

```
db.collection.find({$text:{$search:'abc@test.com'}}).pretty()
```

it gives me all the document in the collection.
i also made the text index on all the fields using this query

```
db.serviceenquiries.createIndex({"$**":"text"})
```

how can i search for email id

Answer (score 5):

Give a try to search phrase:

```
db.collection.find({$text:{$search:"\"abc@test.com\""}}).pretty()
```

Comment: But it slows down the query by a lot